# Is this the best performace way to use Java Stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to create a new list of strings from this array of strings:

```
    String[] groups = {
            "A_group1,AAAAA",
            "A_group2",
            "A_group3",
            "B_group4",
            "B_group5",
            "B_group6,BBBBBBB",
            "C_group7",
            "C_group8",
            "C_group9,CCCCC",
    };
```

where i have to keep strings that start with these prefixes:

```
    Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    mapping.put( "prefix1", "A_" );
    mapping.put( "prefix2", "B_" );
```

I would like to use Java Streams, but I'm a novice with these apis, so  I wrote this code:

```
    mapping.values().forEach( prefix ->
            roles.addAll( stream( groups ).parallel().filter(
                    group -> group.startsWith( prefix )
            ).map(
                    group -> group.split( "," )[0].substring( prefix.length() )
            ).collect( toList() ) )
    );
```

The result is:

```
    [group4, group5, group6, group1, group2, group3]
```

It is correct. But I would like to know if there is a code with better performace

Comment: For such small number of elements, it is not worth doing parallel streams, or even streams at all. Just use good old for loops if speed is what you are after.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: and does your input have `,`? else how does `group.split( "," )` work? .... wondering if you want to build a prefix tree(trie) for this to optimize your lookups!

Comment: Sorry, Yes, in rare case I have to split the string

Comment: I didn't know CodeReview, next time I'll ask there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is inefficient, and it has nothing to do with the use of streams.

Your outer loop should be on "groups", and then check against the set of values of mapping, which is O(1) complexity. Something like:

```
Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>(mapping.values());
stream( groups ).filter(g -> filter.contains(g.split("_")[0] + "_")). ...
```

If you loop over the filter you end up looping over groups n-times, making the complexity O(n^2) instead of linear.

The rest looks fine to me: no big changes if you use stream API or plain old for loop. Just be aware that parallelizing the stream makes sense if you have a large number of groups; for a small number of groups the overhead of managing a parallelization could make the execution actually slower

Comment: `mapping.values()` returns a `Collection`, how are you able to assign it to a `Set` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use `startsWith`, because I have only the prefix of the string

Comment: @DiegoMarcolungo if you are able to recognize the prefix like in the example (because you may split on underscore) then amend the .filter() call to check your group.split('')[0] again with Set.contains()

Comment: if you are not able to recognize the prefix by just looking at the group name, and you are very worried about performance, then you may want to use a prefix-tree.